# How to pass parameter to diffrent page using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help. I need to pass some value to different page using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
  <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Latitude:</span>
  <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Latitude coordinate" ng-model="latitude" ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');">
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-if=" latitude">
  <a ng-click="demo()" target="_blank" href="">Display Location On The Map</a>
</div>
```

Here i need to pass the `Latitude` field value to another page which is opening in new tab. My controller side code is given below.

```
var newCustomer=angular.module('Spesh');
newCustomer.controller('newController',function($scope,$state){
  $scope.demo=function(){
    var base_url = "index.html#" 
    var url = $state.href('map', {}); 
    window.open(base_url+url,'_blank'); 
  }
})
```

> map.html:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div id="dvMap" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;">{{latitude}}</div>
```

In this page i want to display that passed value.My [full plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/uD8zenLW3UMbnDcbymFg?p=preview) is here. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ui-router`, you have all the magic in your hands of navigation using the `stateparameters`.

**Dont use plain javascript navigations, use `$state.go` instead**

You can use the `$stateParams` of `ui-router` to navigate through the views.

Check, I added an optional parameter `latitude` on `state change`

**routes.js**

```
var Admin = angular.module('Spesh', ['ui.router']);
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .state('new', {
      url: '/new',
      templateUrl: 'new.html',
      controller: 'newController'
    })
    .state('map', {
      url: '/map?latitude',
      templateUrl: 'map.html',
      controller: 'mapController'
    })
})
```

Your **mapcontroller.js**:

```
var login=angular.module('Spesh');
login.controller('mapController',function($scope,$state,$stateParams){
  alert($stateParams.latitude);
 $scope.latitude = $stateParams.latitude;
})
```

**newcontroller.js**:

```
var newCustomer=angular.module('Spesh');
newCustomer.controller('newController',function($scope,$state){
  $scope.demo=function(){
    var base_url = "index.html#" 
    $state.go("map", {latitude: $scope.latitude});

    -------to open in a new tab-------

     $state.go("map", {latitude: $scope.latitude});
     var url = $state.href('map', {latitude: $scope.latitude});
     window.open(url,'_blank'); 


  }
})
```

**`$state.go("map", {latitude: $scope.latitude});`**, this is important line

**To open in a new tab**

```
 $state.go("map", {latitude: $scope.latitude});
 var url = $state.href('map', {latitude: $scope.latitude});
 window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Here is the your Plunker link.

[Check the changed plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cuDzGObskqjDPR0NedqS?p=preview)

Comment: @subhra, please check my answer and the plunker I have given.

Comment: yes,its coming. But it should open in different page after click on the link.